# MVVM and business layer architecture

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, architecture, business-logic

I am developing an application which I have just finished doing :

- Domain layer - made in Domain Driven Design way, so I have some logic here
- Data access layer - with nhibernate and UnitOfWork - Repository pattern
- UI layer - MVVM with Caliburn.Micro

Now the question is : where I put my logic?

According to

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185448/mvvm-clarification

I have to split the application logic from the domain logic but I do a simple example :

I have a ViewModel that only to charge a person from the db and allow the changes, then I will have 3 methods (to keep simply the example):

```
LoadPerson ( id )
SavePerson (Person )
CanEditPerson ( id )
```

The first 2 must call the corresponding methods of my `UoW` but must do so directly ?

In an earlier application made ​​with asp.net I created a businessLayer with a facade for each page, so the page calls the `LoadPerson` of the facade and then BL call the `LoadPerson` of the data access layer.

It's a correct way that I could use here?

But in that case, the pages were very complex and worked on a variety of objects: I had 6 page (full of tab and accordion) for an application that was based on about 100 items.

Here I understand that the view must be very simple and possibly work on a single object, I should then have a facade in the BL for each `ViewModel`?

`CanEditPerson` must be a method that verifies the rules established to determine whether the current user can change the person or not. It seems very logical domain (the buyers have to establish pemessi) own the copyright but I do not know how to handle this thing in `DomainLayer`, I would be much more natural to have the method in a `BusinessLayer`

Comment: For your DataAcessLayer i recommend you this Repository Framework: http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/

I think the example on it, will help you to find the answere.

Comment: i will look it, but i have done a repository in a way i like very much. and my question is on facade pattern e Domain logic

Answer (score 0):

You can also Create a one Model Here and declare Property and Method in it.
like

```
 public class Person
    {
   //Declare your property

     LoadPerson ( id )
     {

      }
     SavePerson (Person )
     { 

      }
     CanEditPerson ( id )
     {

      }
    }
```

Now You have to just create Property of Person class in your ViewModel so you can easily access their property as well as Methods.

```
private Person _PersonDetails;

public Person PersonDetails
{
    get { return _PersonDetails??(_PersonDetails=new Person());}
    set { _PersonDetails = value;}
}
```

Comment: and what about persistence ignorance of my entity? and CanEditPerson can involve other entities to work, in some case i have complex stored procedure to decide if a record can be edited or not (for example an activity can be edited if no person owned it, it's in a particular status and so on)